# Convert this language to Context Free Grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm having trouble understanding how to convert this language to context free grammar.

$\{a^ib^jc^k\mid i > k, 0\le j \lt3, k \ge 0\}$

Part im getting stuck on is how to deal with a and c, whenever a c is added, you must also add an a, but with them at opposite ends of the string how do you properly build grammar for it? Since the below is not possible:

\begin{align}
C &\rightarrow aC \\
C &\rightarrow c
\end{align}

I've read the below post many times and tried to apply it but still not able to get it.

[How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free)

Someone able to show me how this can be done?

Comment: Did you try making a PDA for this language? Because, making a PDA is relatively easier than directly coming up with a CFG.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prove the language is context-free, showing a PDA that accepts $L$ is enough.

Sometimes, formulating the rules that generate exactly the language $L$ is not so trivial; in such cases you can start by a constructing the PDA that accepts $L$, then convert it to a CFG.

The transformation PDA $\rightarrow$ CFG can be found:

[Lecture notes](http://www1.idc.ac.il/toky/Automata/Material/pda2cfg.pdf)

[Answer on this site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51658/how-to-convert-pda-to-cfg)

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever a $c$ is added, you must also add an $a$, but with them at opposite ends of the string how do you properly build grammar for it?

The production rule you are looking for looks like the following,

$$X\to aXc.$$

The full context-free grammar for the given language can be

$$S\to aS \mid aSc \mid a \mid ab \mid abb \mid abbb. $$