# Converting PDA to CFG

Tags: automata, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

[image]

I am trying to understand this example of converting PDA to CFG but I am not getting the idea quite right. I do have the general understanding of theorem that if $p,q\ \epsilon\ Q $ and $X \varepsilon\ \Gamma$ for $[pXq]$ we have include the sequence of derivations which would pop *X*
from the stack.

I partially understand what is going on but I cannot seem to understand how do I unroll the productions to form strings so I can understand it clearly. Take the production (5) in the example for instance. From what I understand it we are in state p we want to pop A and in the end we should be in state p with empty stack. As we are reading *0* we have zero in the production followed by $[pAq][qAp]$, this is the thing which I am not understanding because if we look at the PDA there is no way of going to *q* on reading 0. I would like to know what really is going on.

A related question is answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51658/how-to-convert-pda-to-cfg)
but I cannot understand it how to clear my confusion.

Comment: Source: the slide you show is from a deck produced by Marta Vomlelová, on Automata and Grammars- TIN071.

Comment: I wanted to share link but I cannot for English only Czech slides are public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic intuition right.
The variable $[p,A,q]$ represents the set of (strings accepted by) computations from state $p$ to state $q$ that will pop the topmost symbol $A$ from the stack.

[image]

Technicaly the relation between grammar $G$ and pda $M$ is given on the top of the slide you show.

Then the construction follows recursion. If the pda pops $A$ but pushes $B_1B_2B3$ the grammar will replace the computation on $A$ starting in $p$ and ending in $q$ into three separate computations $[q_1,B_1,q_2][q_2,B_1,q_3][q_3,B_1,q]$. Here the intermediate states $q_2,q_3$ are unknown and are *guessed* by the grammar. Only $q_1$ is known, as it is the state where the pda instruction moves to.

[image]

Your observation is right. This standard construction might introduce triplets $[p,A,q]$ that will be useless. In your example there will be no computations from $q$ to $p$ so a triplet $[q,A,p]$ is never used in a succesful derivation. That is not problamatic. The construction just produces all possibilities, and variables that turn out to be useless can be removed afterwards if one really wants.

**Note.** The other question you link to uses a different Sipser style automaton model! There stack symbols are pushed one by one without popping at the same time. To add to the confusion the [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51676/4287) given at that question perfectly matches the construction from your slide!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it has cleared many points for me